# Given that first toss is heads, what is probability that all $5$ tosses are heads?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

### **Problem**

Toss a Coin $5$ times.
Let $H_1 = $ First Toss is $\mathbb{HEAD}$.
Let $H_A = $ All $5$ Tosses are $\mathbb{HEAD}$.
Find $P(H_A\mid H_1)$

The answer says that $P(H_A\mid H_1) = \frac{1}{16}$, but I don't agree with that.

### **My Approach**

$$P(H_1) = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$P(H_A) = \frac{1}{32}$$
$$P(H_A\mid H_1)=\frac{P(H_A\cap H_1)}{P(H_1)}$$

$$P(H_A∩H_1) =  \frac{1}{2} *  \frac{1}{32} =  \frac{1}{64}$$

$$P(H_A\mid H_1) =  \frac{\frac{1}{64}}{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{32}$$

Why does my answer not match $\frac{1}{16}$? Where did I made mistake?

Comment: $P(H_a\cap H_1)\neq P(H_a)\cdot P(H_1)$. That would be true if the events were independent, but they are not. In fact, $P(H_1\mid H_a)=1$.

Comment: the problem is in calculating the probability of the intersection. Since they are not independent, you can't simply multiply the probabilities

Comment: $H_a\cap H_1=H_a$ ($H_a=\{HHHHH\}, H_1=\{HTTTT, HTTTH, \dots, HHHHH\}$), so $P(H_a\cap H_1)=P(H_a)=\frac{1}{32}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H_1$ be the event that First Toss is $\mathcal{Heads}$.
Let $H_A$ be the event that All Tosses are $\mathcal{Heads}$.

> Now, as per [Baye's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem)
> \begin{align}
> \ P(B |A) &= \frac{P(B).P(A|B)}{P(A)} \\\\
>  & = \frac{P(B).P(A\cap B)}{P(A).P(B)} \\\\
> & = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)} \\
> \end{align}

Thus,

> $$P(H_A|H_1) = \frac{P(H_A\cap H_1)}{P(H_1)} \qquad(\text{This can also be derived from definition of Conditional Probability})$$

Since we have $5$ **Empty Blanks** to fill.

- **For** Sample Space $(S)$, every Empty Blank can take $\mathcal{Two}$ values $\mathcal{Heads \space or \space Tails}$

  Thus, $n(S)=2\times2\times2\times2\times2 = 32$
- **For**  $H_A \cap H_1$, every Empty Blank can take only $\mathcal{One}$ value $\mathcal{Heads}$

  Thus, $n(H_A \cap H_1)=1\times1\times1\times1\times1 = 1$
- **For**  $H_1$, First Empty Blank can take only $\mathcal{One}$ value $\mathcal{Heads}$, remaining empty Blanks can take $\mathcal{Two}$ values $\mathcal{Heads \space or \space Tails}$

  Thus, $n(H_1)=1\times2\times2\times2\times2 = 16$

> $$P(H_A|H_1) = \frac{ \frac {n(H_A \cap H_1)}{n(S)} } {\frac {n(H_1)}{n(S)}}$$

On Putting values

> **$$P(H_A|H_1) = \frac{1}{16}$$**

---

**The Image for Same is attached here.**
[image: Image Solution]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.